# Re-factoring/optimisng code

Tags: java, android

I've written a method to try and optimise my code as the same thing was being called 3 different times, however, rewritting this method has just to a similar issue. It basically does the same thing but just changes a variable based upon a parameter.

```
public void checkChance(String spawnX, int chance, int value) {
        if (spawnX.equals("smallX")) {
            if (player.getX() > screenWidth / 2) {
                if (chance > value) {
                    smallX = random.nextInt(screenWidth - (screenWidth / 2)) + (screenWidth / 2);
                } else {
                    smallX = random.nextInt((screenWidth / 2) - 0);
                }
            } else {
                if (chance > value) {
                    smallX = random.nextInt((screenWidth / 2) - 0);
                } else {
                    smallX = random.nextInt(screenWidth - (screenWidth / 2)) + (screenWidth / 2);
                }
            }
        } else if (spawnX.equals("mediumX")) {
            if (player.getX() > screenWidth / 2) {
                if (chance > value) {
                    mediumX = random.nextInt(screenWidth - (screenWidth / 2)) + (screenWidth / 2);
                } else {
                    mediumX = random.nextInt((screenWidth / 2) - 0);
                }
            } else {
                if (chance > value) {
                    mediumX = random.nextInt((screenWidth / 2) - 0);
                } else {
                    mediumX = random.nextInt(screenWidth - (screenWidth / 2)) + (screenWidth / 2);
                }
            }
        } else if (spawnX.equals("largeX")) {
            if (player.getX() > screenWidth / 2) {
                if (chance > value) {
                    largeX = random.nextInt(screenWidth - (screenWidth / 2)) + (screenWidth / 2);
                } else {
                    largeX = random.nextInt((screenWidth / 2) - 0);
                }
            } else {
                if (chance > value) {
                    largeX = random.nextInt((screenWidth / 2) - 0);
                } else {
                    largeX = random.nextInt(screenWidth - (screenWidth / 2)) + (screenWidth / 2);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Ideally I'd like it so I only need the part in the body of each if (that checks what spawnX equals) and just change what variable get's set. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without digging too much into the design with regards to the method signature and what goal this code is accomplishing *[why is it subtracting 0? `screenWidth - (screenWidth / 2)` will always simply equal `screenWidth / 2`]*, I think something like the following would be clearer with less duplication:

```
public void checkChance(final String spawnX, final int chance, final int value) {
    int intermediary;

    if (player.getX() > screenWidth / 2) {
        if (chance > value) {
            intermediary = random.nextInt(screenWidth - (screenWidth / 2)) + (screenWidth / 2);
        } else {
            intermediary = random.nextInt((screenWidth / 2) - 0);
        }
    } else {
        if (chance > value) {
            intermediary = random.nextInt((screenWidth / 2) - 0);
        } else {
            intermediary = random.nextInt(screenWidth - (screenWidth / 2)) + (screenWidth / 2);
        }
    }

    if (spawnX.equals("smallX")) {
        smallX = intermediary;
    } else if (spawnX.equals("mediumX")) {
        mediumX = intermediary;
    } else if (spawnX.equals("largeX")) {
        largeX = intermediary;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not subtracting 0, 0 is the minimum value. I left it here for my own benefit. But thanks for the tidy up!

Comment: Again it's not subtracting, I know it would equal screenWidth / 2, but I want it to start from screenWidth / 2 to screenWidth (it's not screenWidth minus anything)

Comment: Which can be simplified even further if the arithmetic I mentioned is reduced, but without knowing the actual calculations that are missing, it isn't possible to say.

Comment: What those calculations are doing is creating a random number based on the player's x. For example, I call this method like this: checkChance("largeX", chance, 60); and chance is a random number from 0 - 100. So in this instance there's a 40% chance for the weight to spawn within the side of the screen the players on.

Comment: What are the actual arguments to `random.nextInt` in your scenarios, meaning how are they different from the code you posted in the question?

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning, you could do something like this (pseudo-code)

```
TYPE tmpX = (conditionSmall) ? smallX: ((conditionMedium)? medium : largeX);
```

Then, simply make your change to tmpX. Since Java variables (other than primitives) are really pointers to objects, your tmpX will point to the object you wish to modify.

Comment: int tmpX = ((spawnX.equals("smallX")) ? smallX : ((spawnX.equals("mediumX")) ? mediumX : largeX)); - I ended up with this, but it's not setting the variables correctly as they all spawn at the same X position. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ah! your smallX etc. are primitives (ints). I didn't see them declared and didn't pay attention to the details from which it can be deduced. Laz gave you the right answer.